# Calling and running a jar file from java in the same console

Tags: java, process, runtime, exec

I am trying to write a program which is able to open any .jar file from a given directory. Having used `Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + contents[selectInt - 1]);` where a typical value of `contents[selectInt - 1]` would be something like `C:\Users\Kieran\Desktop\CharCount.jar` (I've tested and that does give the full filepath to the jar file), no command prompt window pops up and nothing appears in the current window. Entering `java -jar C:\Users\Kieran\Desktop\CharCount.jar` into the console works just fine. Full code as below:

```
package listfiles;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ListFiles {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static File folder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set folder to search
        String filePath;
        final int LENGTH = args.length;
        if (LENGTH > 0) {
            filePath = args[0];
        } else {
            System.out.print("File to search (or \"QUIT\" to exit): ");
            filePath = sc.next();
            if (filePath.equals("QUIT")) {
                exit();
            }
        }
        folder = new File(filePath);

        //Create an array of folder contents with the extension .jar and print it
        File[] contents = folder.listFiles(new JarFilter());
        System.out.print("Search in \"" + filePath + "\" found " + contents.length + " result");
        if (contents.length != 1) {
            System.out.print("s");
        }
        System.out.print(":\n\n");
        int i = 0;
        for (File file : contents) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + file);
        }

        //Allow the user to run a jar file
        int selectInt = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please select a file number to open or \"QUIT\" to exit: ");
            String select = sc.next();
            if (select.equals("QUIT")) {
                exit();
            }
            try {
                selectInt = Integer.parseInt(select);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((selectInt > 0) && (selectInt <= contents.length)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("java -jar " + contents[selectInt - 1]);
            Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + contents[selectInt - 1]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Opening .jar file failed.");
            exit();
        }
    }

    private static void exit() {
        System.out.print("\n\nExiting...\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

JarFilter simply accepts .jar files (and works).

I'd be very grateful for any light that could be shed.

EDIT: The code for CharCount.jar is as follows:

```
package charcount;

public class CharCount
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (String str : args)
        {
            System.out.println("\"" + str + "\" has " + str.length() + " characters.");
            i += str.length();
        }
        System.out.println("Total characters: " + i);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the JDK is on the path in a newly created process?  Did you check the process' `exitValue()` to make sure it actually started? You need to extract just the part that invokes a jar file to its own main class with no oher code, and step through it in your IDE debugger.

Comment: Adding a line: `System.out.println(ps.exitValue());` directly after calling the process yields an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited` `at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Unknown Source)` `at listfiles.ListFiles.main(ListFiles.java:73)`

Comment: I'll add the code for the other jar to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to run it from the cmd, have you attempted:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar FILEPATH");
```

Or in your case:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar" + contents[selectInt - 1]);
```

----UPDATE----

To keep the prompt open use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java -jar " + contents[selectInt - 1]);
```

Comment: This is not multi-platform, maybe the OP does not care about this, but he has to know.

Comment: I'm not worried about multi-platform, but thanks for the info. When I run this I get a very brief flash of a window which immediately closes - is there a way to keep this open such as with the PAUSE function in a batch file?

Comment: No change I'm afraid - using a screen recorder I managed to get a faint still of the popup window and the caption is java.exe in program files. Works just fine if I type it into the command prompt.

Comment: It may be worth noting that there is no extra window at all when running from Eclipse - this only occurs when compiled to a runnable jar and accessed from the command prompt

Comment: I miskeyed my last attempt - your edit was successful! Thankyou!

Comment: Good! Almost had me installing Eclipse to check... haha